# ExpressJS + Mongoose : Can't update a record in findByIdAndUpdate mongoose's function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm a newbie in JS, NodeJS, Mongodb and I am trying to figure out my issue have.

```
exports.like = function (req, res, next) {
    PostModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.postIdLike, req.body, {new : true},function (err, post) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(this.getErrorMessage(err));
            return next(err);
        } else {
            var numberPeopleLike = post.Like.PeopleLike.length;
            var currentUserID = req.body.CurrentUserID;
            console.log(numberPeopleLike);
            if (numberPeopleLike === 0) {
                post.Like.PeopleLike.push({id: currentUserID, flag: true});
                post.Like.NumberLike += 1;
                var data = {
                    value: post,
                    message: "Like",
                    status: 1
                };
                res.json(data);
                next();
            } else {
                // post like != null
                console.log("numberPeopleLike");
                for (var i = 0; i < numberPeopleLike; i++) {
                    if (post.Like.PeopleLike[i].id === currentUserID && post.Like.PeopleLike[i].flag === true) {
                        // user Liked
                        post.Like.NumberLike -= 1;
                        post.Like.PeopleLike[i].flag = false;
                        var data = {
                            value: post,
                            message: "Undo Like",
                            status: 0
                        };
                        res.json(data);
                        next();
                    } else {
                        // user don't like
                        post.Like.NumberLike += 1;
                        post.Like.PeopleLike.push({id: currentUserID, flag: true});
                        var data = {
                            value: post,
                            message: "Like",
                            status: 1
                        };
                        res.json(data);
                        next();
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    });
};
```

***My Problem :***

The findByIdAndUpdate function isn't update result code in `if(numberPeopleLike === 0)` condition. Although data json has value , the result can't update on collections. What's wrong?

[UPDATE]
When I implement with `PUT` method to excute function (Update )then
Value of `data` in `if(numberPeopleLike === 0 )` condition

```
{
  "value": {
    "_id": "5717938a857e9c8a0e71a512",
    "IDMemberProfile": "5711114c2b5ecdf11a23947d",
    "Title": "test",
    "Content": "test",
    "Status": 1,
    "__v": 0,
    "Like": {
      "NumberLike": 1,
      "PeopleLike": [
        {
          "id": "570f932dfc642a4f1df5b450",
          "flag": true,
          "_id": "5717a9e42ae3ca5f12180844"
        }
      ]
    },
    "PostTime": "2016-04-20T14:34:50.973Z"
  },
  "message": "Like",
  "status": 1
}
```

But when I get `GET` list post in collection , this document can't update

```
{
      "_id": "5717938a857e9c8a0e71a512",
      "IDMemberProfile": "5711114c2b5ecdf11a23947d",
      "Title": "test",
      "Content": "test",
      "Status": 1,
      "__v": 0,
      "Like": {
        "NumberLike": 0,
        "PeopleLike": []
      },
      "PostTime": "2016-04-20T14:34:50.973Z"
    }
```

Comment: please don't post images of your json, but rather post the JSON itself.

Comment: @jmugz3: I updated my question.